Comparing two types of data in bigQuery
We have a very big dataset. And I need to get all the values that are mapping from the source attributes to normalized attributes in my json. The relation between normalised and source is that if the source_key in normalized values is same like the source_attributes keys then we should return all their names.
My input is somewhat like this:
  "source_attributes": {
    "desirability": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "000000002"
        }
      ]
    },
    "isbn-13": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "9781934568392"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "normalized": {
    "isbn-13": [
      {
        "properties": {
          "attributeId": "85984",
          "multiselect": "N",
          "domain": "pcs",
          "display_attribute_name": "ISBN-13",
          "taxonomy_version": "urn:taxonomy:pcs2.0",
          "attributeName": "ISBN-13"
        },
        "values": [
          {
            "display_attr_name": "ISBN-13",
            "locale": "en_US",
            "value": "9781934568392",
            "isPrimary": "true",
            "source_value": "9781934568392",
            "source_key": "isbn-13"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

My desired output is something like this:

The query I wrote fetches all the values from the data that has source attributes and normalized but how do I compare the values as the structurally both the elements are different?
SELECT json_extract(element_json, '$.source_attributes') as source_att, json_extract(element_json, '$.normalized') as normal
FROM `data`
where json_value(element_json,'$.source')='TEST'
limit 1000;


In your puzzle, I am seeing a single JSON object that contains two fields ... "source_attributes" and "normalized".  I am sensing that you want to know whether or not a field contained in "source_attributes" is also contained in "normalized".  Is that correct?  The values of the of the fields don't matter?

Yess that correct @kolban

The following is a SQL fragment that illustrates one possible technique:
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION keys(val JSON)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS r"""
return Object.keys(val)
""";


WITH data AS (
  SELECT JSON '{"source": {"a": 1,"b": 2,"c": 3},"target": {"a": 2,"d": 4}}'  as json_data
),
source_keys as (
  SELECT keys(json_data.source) AS s_keys FROM data
),
target_keys as (
  SELECT keys(json_data.target) as t_keys FROM data
)
SELECT s_key_t, CASE WHEN s_key_t IN UNNEST((SELECT t_keys from target_keys)) THEN s_key_t ELSE null END as t_key_t from UNNEST((SELECT s_keys from source_keys)) as s_key_t

In this story, we assume a JSON object that itself contains two child objects called source and target.  Our goal is to find out which fields in source are also present in target where we care about their names/identities and not their values.
We use a UDF to return an array of field names from both the source and the target and then compare them by asking (logically) for each of the keys in the source field name array, does the same name exist in the target field name array.
